# jest.spyOn mock return value not returning value

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, spyon

The code I'm trying to test:

```
const utils = require('../utils/utils');

        let imageBuffer;
        try {
            imageBuffer = await utils.retrieveImageFromURI(params)
            console.log(imageBuffer) // comes back as undefined when I mock the utils.retreieveImageFromURI
            if (!imageBuffer || imageBuffer.length < 1024) {
                throw new Error(`Retrieve from uri (${params.camera.ingest.uri}) was less than 1kb in size - indicating an error`)
            }
            console.log(`${params.camera.camId} - Successful Ingestion from URI`);
        } catch (err) {
            reject({ 'Task': `Attempting to pull image from camera (${params.camera.camId}) at ${params.camera.ingest.uri}`, 'Error': err.message, 'Stack': err.stack })
            return;
        }
```

Specifically, I'm trying to mock the utils.retrieveImageFromURI function - which has API calls and other things in it.

When I try to mock the function using spyOn I am trying it like so:

```
describe("FUNCTION: ingestAndSave", () => {
    let fakeImageBuffer = Array(1200).fill('a').join('b'); // just get a long string
    console.log(fakeImageBuffer.length) //2399
    let retrieveImageFromURISpy
    beforeAll(() => {
        retrieveImageFromURISpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'retrieveImageFromURI').mockReturnValue(fakeImageBuffer) 
    })

    test("Will call retrieveImageFromURI", async () => {
        await ingest.ingestAndSave({camera:TEST_CONSTANTS.validCameraObject, sourceQueueURL:"httpexamplecom", receiptHandle: "1234abcd"})
        expect(retrieveImageFromURISpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks()
    })
    afterAll(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks()
    })
})
```

When I do this, I get a console log that imageBuffer (which is supposed to be the return of the mocked function) is `undefined` and that, in turn, triggers the thrown Error that `"Retrieve from uri ...."` ... which causes my test to fail.  I know I could wrap the test call in a try/catch but the very next test will be a "does not throw error" test... so this needs to be solved.

It's not clear to me why the mockReturnValue isn't getting returned.

**Other steps:**

I've gone to the REAL `retrieveImageFromURI` function and added a console log - it is not running.

I've changed mockReturnValue to mockImplementation like so:

```
retrieveImageFromURISpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'retrieveImageFromURI').mockImplementation(() => {
            console.log("Here")
            return fakeImageBuffer
        })
```

And it does NOT console log 'here'.  I'm unsure why not.

I have also tried to return it as a resolved Promise, like so:

```
retrieveImageFromURISpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'retrieveImageFromURI').mockImplementation(() => {
    console.log("Here")
    return Promise.resolve(fakeImageBuffer)
})
```

Note, this also doesn't console log.

I've also tried to return the promise directly with a mockReturnValue:

```
`retrieveImageFromURISpy = jest.spyOn(utils, 'retrieveImageFromURI').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(fakeImageBuffer)`)
```